# CLIツールにPythonスクリプトを渡して、柔軟にカスタマイズできるようにしたい

Tags: python, command-line

## 環境

- Python 3.6

## 背景

PythonでCLIツールを作成しています。
あるWebサービスから情報を取得して、以下のようなフォーマットでCSVファイルを出力するようなCLIです。
実際には20～40列あります。

```
name,a_seconds,b_seconds
Alice,3600,1800
Bob,3600,3600
```

コマンドは以下のように実行します。

```
$ python print_csv.py
```

## やりたいこと

CSVのいくつかの列は、ユーザがカスタマイズして出力できるようにしたいです。
たとえば、`a_b_hours`列を出力したい場合、以下のような設定をコマンドの外から渡せるようにしたいです。

```
column_name = "a_b_hours"

def column_func(df):
    df[column_name] = df["a_secons"] + df["b_seconds"]
```

出力結果

```
name,a_seconds,b_seconds,a_b_hours
Alice,3600,1800,1.5
Bob,3600,3600,2
```

## 質問

上記の機能を提供するために、コマンドの外から、Pythonスクリプトを渡すにはどうすればよいでしょうか？
以下のようなコマンドを実行できるようにしたいです。

```
$ python main.py 3
num = 3

$ python main.py 3 --script custom.py
num * num = 9
```

main.py

```py
def custom_print(num: int):
    """実際には、10～100行の処理を想定している"""
    print(f"num = {num}")

if if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("num", type=int, help="出力する整数")
    parser.add_argument("--script", help="外部から注入するスクリプト")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.script is not None:
        # args.scriptを使ってcustom_printを変更する
        custom_print = ...

    custom_print(args.num)
```

custom.py
カスタマイズしたい場合、Pythonスクリプトを作成して、このファイルをコマンドに渡します。

```py
def custom_print(num: int):
    print(f"num * num = {num*num}")
```

#### 考えたこと

- `exec`を使えばよいんですかね？

Comment: 質問を整理すると、「Pythonスクリプト実行時に引数として別のPythonファイルを渡して適宜読み込ませる」が適切に見えますが、この認識で正しいですか？

Comment: カスタマイズの範囲がはっきりしませんが、初めの例を見る限り出力結果を元に数値の計算をさせたいだけであれば、私なら`awk`などを使って結果を加工する方法を選びます。 - 参考: [一つのことを、うまくやれ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX哲学)

Comment: >「Pythonスクリプト実行時に引数として別のPythonファイルを渡して適宜読み込ませる」
はい、正しいです。

Comment: >私ならawkなどを使って結果を加工する方法を選びます。
実際には、もう少し複雑な処理も想定している（累計値や移動平均の算出など）ので、awkで対応するのは難しいです。
また、awkがないWindowsでもCLIツールを利用できるようにしたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec`でいいんじゃない?と思いますが、ちゃんと実装するならば`importlib`モジュールを使いたいところです。(何を持って「ちゃんと実装」なのか、と突っ込まれると辛いところですが)

そんなわけで興味があったので、調べました。
調べた、と言っても、リファレンスマニュアルを眺めていたら[そのまんまのサンプル](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly)があっただけなんですが。

```py
# coding: utf-8
# hoge.py

import sys, importlib.util, os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        sys.stderr.write('%s <script>\n' % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]

    print('load module.')
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(name, filename)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    sys.modules[name] = module

    print('call function.')
    module.func()
```

```py
# coding: utf-8
# piyo.py

import sys

print('load piyo')

def func():
    print('piyo.func().')
```

実行結果。

```
$ python3 hoge.py piyo.py
load module.
load piyo.
call function.
piyo.func()
```